# Which levels have bonus secret levels in them?

Tags: macos, dungeon-keeper

Sometimes there are bonus cubes found in the levels, which allow you to play a secret level to grant special bonuses (for example: transfer a nice creature to the next "normal" level, or whatever).

Which levels have these cubes?  I want to know when to search.

Comment: Are you looking for a complete list of the *hidden dungeon secrets* or just a list of hidden levels?

Comment: @Mario A list of levels that contain **secrets of bonus level type**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was taken from this FAQ over on [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/197183-dungeon-keeper/faqs/60666):

There's six secret bonus stages to be found in Dungeon Keeper, 
however, only five of them are accessible due to what seems to be an 
error in level 14: Sleepiburgh. Also some of the bonus levels designs 
are pretty messed up. Certain doors which are supposed to be locked 
are left open and some levels miss a "Transfer Creature" special 
making the level a rather pointless exercise. Each dungeon special 
you find will unlock the bonus levels in consecutive order, but 
because you can only go through the levels in a single fixed order 
you can never unlock Secret 5. It is actually a good thing, because 
that level is almost as dull as the first one. A small overview:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Level    Unlock in   Best Reward       Bugged                  ║
║════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════║
║ Secret 1 level 8*    Vampire(10)       No Creature Transfer    ║
║ Secret 2 level 9*    Vampire(10)       -                       ║  
║ Secret 3 level 15*   Horned Reaper(7)$ -                       ║
║ Secret 4 level 17*   Witch(9)          -                       ║
║ Secret 5 N/A         Dragon(8)         Inaccessible level      ║
║ Secret 6 Full moon   -                 No Creature Transfer &  ║
║          date                          No creature to transfer ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
 * = Provided that you find the all "Locate Hidden Realm" dungeon
     specials.
 $ = Could argue; level 10 Hell Hound has better use in some cases
```

Difficulty ranks between `*` and `*****` with 6 stars denoting insane or 
unfair game play due to problems with the level design. My own 
experience tells that the bonuses are either incredibly easy or 
fiendishly difficult. Secrets 2,3 and 4 are well doable and you 
should definitely try them out. In Secret 3 one of my strategies is 
to slap the Horned Reaper abundantly, ever felt like doing that? >:) 
The other three bonus stages are hardly worth the effort (if at all 
enjoyable).

Since the game is easy to rescript I have edited the necessary 
levels myself to fix the problems and make them playable (including 
the missing "Locate Hidden Realm" bonus in Sleepiburgh). If there's 
enough interest I'll place a .zip file on the Internet so you can 
play the game as it is supposed to be. Also, Secrets 1 and 5 have 
become just a bit easier, so they're not as lame as they were 
before. :P

**Secret 1**

```
Game Time:  38000 (~40 minutes)
Goal:       Either one of the following conditions to win: 
             -Kill all heroes on the map
             -Move one of your creatures in the center of the gems
Spells:     "Posses"
Start Gold: 0
Reward:     Vampire(10) for each goal you clear
            (but no "Creature Transfer to apply it on) XD
Difficulty: ******
Initial Creatures: Dragon(5)
```

This level is not very funny at all. I've played it a few times, but 
never got to the end. Then after I got hold of the DK level editor I 
found out that even if you manage to win the level you cannot 
transfer any creatures meaning that the level is pointless. Why? 
There's no "Transfer Creature" special to be found in the entire 
level and even if there was one you need an Imp to claim the tile in 
order to use the special. So, basically I'm only going to give a 
synopisys of this terribly programmed bonus stage. I bet none of the 
programmers ever actually played it.

You start out with a Dragon (very slow when controlled) walk over 
the lava, break some doors, kills some enemies and find a Bile 
Demon(7). Walk around with the Bile Demon (slow as well), kill more 
enemies and find a Mistress. She's faster, but there's lots of 
boulders around here meaning that you need to walk around very 
carefully. Kill more enemies and find a level 8 Vampire in the prison 
to the north. Here's where I get stuck. The path to the west has some 
Monks, but it only leads to a dead end with an useable "Level up" 
special. So go east, you'll come across a lone neutral Giant(5). 
Walk/fly further south, break another door and you'll come across a 
very large group of heroes and Knight. This group is nearly 
unbeatable because there's so many of them attacking you all at the 
same time. But suppose you can beat those by some fluke, then you 
need to continue on and find some more high leveled creatures which 
are annoying as well. Then near the end where you find the area 
around the gems you encounter 8 level 8 Monks. That's insane. The 
only possible way I could think of to beat them is casting 
"Whirlwind" to push them all into the lava draining their energy at a 
fixed rate and keeping them there, until they die. Even with the lava 
damage it still takes some time to kill them. If you kill them all a 
level 10 Vampire appears, and if you enter that prescribed area a 
different level 10 Vampire appears.

I suppose the only practical way to beat this level without cheating 
is getting to the Vampire and then blazing through the entire level 
towards the gems sustaining damage and using his Heal ability as you 
fly through it. But without "Transfer Creature" it's rather pointless 
to do that.

**Secret 2**

```
Game Time:  3300 (~4.5 minutes)
Goal:       Kill all your Imps
Spells:     "Posses", "Lightning"
Start Gold: 1200
Reward:     level 10 Vampire
Difficulty: *
Creatures: 49x Imp(various)
```

In the script referred to as the: "Slap the Imp" level. Although, 
you'll be doing little slapping as far as that is too tedious (and to 
RSI sensitive imo). There's more simple and intelligent ways to get 
the job done. An nice bonus level to get an easy Vampire, but I 
wonder what the "Lightning spell is used for... You can't damage your 
creatures with it.

From the start move the cursor to the far west and dig out some of 
the tiles. You'll find three good Imps around here. Let them do 
battle; this number of Imps lost by this is only marginally. Get the 
8 most experienced Imps in your hand and have some others dig out the 
rocks to the north of these Imps who went good. Two Boulder traps 
appear here (that's the first time you'll be happy to see those :D). 
Quickly drop your high leveled Imps in front of it and get some more 
for the second trap. This way the strongest Imps have been 
obliterated from the lot. Now dig west to find a good Hell Hound(7).

This dog will sniff out your Dungeon heart and attacks it pronto. 
Let him do so, and your Imps will defend the mother hoard at all 
costs. Meaning that they come back to the Heart without you having to 
anything for it. But wait, once all the Imps are gone more Imps 
appear! 10 level 10 Imps show up and you'd better pick some of them 
up... Imps may be weak, but 10 against 1 is too much, even for this 
Hell Hound. Let him tear the Imps apart one or two at a time. Once 
they've all been annihilated a Vampire mysteriously appears from the 
Heart. He should be able to take out the two headed dog with no 
effort. Congratulations, now use the "Transfer Creatures" spell next 
to the Heart to transport this guy to the next level.

**Secret 3**

```
Game Time:  2200 (~3 minutes)
Goal:       Kill all your Imps
Spells:     "Posses", "Cave-in", "Lightning"
Start Gold: 120000
Reward:     Hell Hound(10)^ or Horned Reaper(7)^ 
Difficulty: *
Initial Creatures:
 49x Imp(various)

 ^ = after applying 4x "Level up" special
```

This level has some devious tricks to it, but if you keep your head 
cool all will work out. First of all, the game messages tell you to 
fry all your Imps using "Lightning", but this isn't going to work at 
all. I suppose this level was coded in an early stage of development 
when the "Lightning" spell still damaged your own creatures, but it 
no longer does... I've found two strategies and both work out very 
smoothly (e.g. no tedious slapping required), but before you leave 
the level make sure to read the paragraph at the bottom:

1. The big Cave-in

   You can still hit them with "Cave-in" and this spell is cheaper to 
   use. But now you think that spell will never cause enough damage to 
   kill the Imps effectively. Well, it can do enough damage, if used 
   properly. First of all, look at the map and find a smallest room with 
   a door. Lock the door of this 3x3 room, now get all your Imps in this 
   room. This may seem hard as just selecting Imps is very slow. To 
   speed this up, select a lot of tiles to dig from near the north.

   Pick up 8 Imps using the ? tab and drop them down into the locked 
   room. Because these Imps can't reach the digging area they become 
   idle. Putting them in the left tab. Click on the working Imps tab and 
   put another 8 into the small room. Rinse and repeat to get all your 
   Imps in this mini-room. Select the "Cave-In" spell, max it out, and 
   release the stone hailstorm by the powers from above. This easily 
   kills off any of the Imps in the room as they can't flee to safer 
   places. Keep on casting the spell over and over until all Imps are 
   gone (if there's only two or three left; you'd better slap them). 
   Congratulations; you won, please read the last paragraph of this 
   section.
2. Horny goes Psycho for the better cause

   Notice the open area to the north? There's something going on there. 
   Get your Imps there and dig out the entire area to find: 4 Level up 
   special, 1 Creature Transfer special and a Horned Reaper(3) sealed of 
   in the northern room. These areas can be claimed as the wall are not 
   reinforced by any color. Now that you have a level 3 Horny, make him 
   mad as hell. For this once you may slap Horny as much as you wish 
   (not too much you don't want to kill him). >:D He'll go berserk and 
   kills off all the Imps for you. In a single slash his scythe should 
   be able to kill an Imp at any level. Please, slap him some more in 
   case he calms down. You don't want that to happen, do you? Once all 
   the Imps are gone you've won. Quickly get the Reaper who's as mad as 
   a hornet in your hand and read the following section:

   Okay? All Imps are dead, now you receive a level 6 Hell Hound, a 
   level 6 Imp and the ability to build Bridges... Go to the top of the 
   area and claim the tiles around here to find some specials over the 
   pits and use the bridges to build... hey, you can just dig around the 
   earth to reach these specials without the bridges. XD I think the 
   walls in this area were supposed to be fortified, but that didn't 
   happen. Anyway, you'll see 4 Level up spells and a Transfer Creature, 
   so you think a level 10 Hound is the best to get from this level? 
   Well, dig north through the center to find a hidden lair with a level 
   3 Horned Reaper (the same one as mentioned for the 2nd strat. Now use 
   the level ups and Transfer the Horned Reaper. If you really want to 
   select the Hound, but Horny will do much better at fighting.

---

**Secret 4**

```
Game Time:  4000 (<3 minutes)
Goal:       Get at least 2 creatures (Imps not included)
Spells:     "Posses", "Heal", "Conceal", "Protect", "Destroy Walls"
Start Gold: 12000
Reward:     Witch(9) 
Difficulty: **
Initial Creatures:
 Imp(1), Skeleton(4)
```

A lot of spells on this short funny level, but I only needed to use 
"Heal" twice; in fact "Conceal" and "Destroy Walls" seem meaningless 
and superfluous. You start this level out completely built in from 
all sides, except the left. Use your single Imp to break single red 
reinforced wall open. Dig up 4 tiles around the wall, but go only 3 
tiles to the right. Otherwise you'll find an enemy Lightning trap 
directly north of your Heart which could kill both your Skeleton and 
Imp. Dig up one more tile to find a lava pit. "Posses" the Skeleton 
and look for the left door, take a single step over the lava 
diagonally to minimize damage, break the door, kill the Fairy(3) 
behind it and walk around to find another Fairy(3) on the opposite 
side. Use "Heal" from the magic tab if needed and "posses" again. 
Walk north past the two Archers(2) and you'll find a small 3x4 room 
with traps. Here's the lay-out:

```
        _| |_       L = Lightning trap  
       |L A a|      W = Word-of-Power trap
       |W l A|      A = Alarm Trap
       |W W A|
       |W A A|      l = Lightning trap (aligned to you)
        -| |-       a = Alarm trap (aligned to you)
```

You'd better stick to hugging the eastern wall as you won't take any 
damage from the Alarm traps. Also any Archers that follow you get 
killed by the Lightning trap placed in the center (it belongs to your 
dungeon). Keep heading north to find many corridors to the left and 
right. The only way to make it through here safely is walking towards 
the braced door straight ahead of you and breaking it so you can 
stand safely in the center tile between the two walls. There should 
be a single Archer here, but it gets killed by the Boulder traps you 
just set of as they all roll around in the same rectangular shape 
around you.

Proceed further to the north (you're almost there) and observe the 
entire line of 7 Boulders dead ahead. The easiest and quickest way to 
avoid them is by triggering one of them, wait for it to get near you, 
side step next to it (triggers another boulder), and sidestep back to 
the previous place. Now walk to the center of the room and look at 
either of the two corridors to the West and East. Pick either one, 
doesn't matter which one, look left & right for any nearby Boulders 
and run into the corridor.

Continue on to the north, kill the single Archer around here, look 
for a door near the top of the map. Walk up to it from the center to 
trigger a poisonous gas trap. Hehe, skeletons are undead and immune 
to gasses. This is your lucky day. The other two tiles have Lightning 
traps, you'd better not hit those. Break the door and take the right 
turn (left leads to a dead end with a Boulder). Break the door at the 
end to find two Imps and a level 9 Witch. Now you have two creatures 
meaning that you've conquered this land. Transport the Skeleton(4) or 
more preferably the Witch(9) using the Dungeon special at your own 
Heart.

---

**Secret 5**

```
Game Time:  40000 (~28 minutes)
Goal:       Kill all Heroes
Spells:     "Posses"
Start Gold: 0
Reward:     - (you 'should' end up with a level 10 Dragon)
Difficulty: ******
Initial Creatures: Imp(10), Demon Spawn(1)
```

Because this level can never be accessed, due to a missing "Locate 
Hidden Realm" dungeon special I never played this level, but 
observing it in the editor shows me that this level is more a 
nuisance than a bonus. I think the idea is to train your level 1 
Demon Spawn into a level 10 Dragon by fighting and applying numerous 
"Level up" dungeon specials on it. No additional enemies are 
triggered by hero doors or actions points, so clearing anything on 
the map should be sufficient.

Anyway, it looks like you start out by forcing the Imp to work on 
digging gold from the gems for your 8 tile treasure room. Pick up the 
Demon Spawn and carry him to the wooden door the far north. Quickly, 
"Posses" him and break the door open to find 3 "Level up" specials. 
If you're too slow the Archers make short work of him. Once the door 
is broken get him back to his lair for some sleep and let the level 
10 Imp claim the tiles on which the specials are located.

Now you have a level 4 Demon Spawn, one which can use the missile 
ability to attack distant enemies. Head west and kill the 2 
Samurai(1), walk further to the west, find & use another Level up 
special, look out for the Boulder near the bottom of the screen. 
Cross the lava and kill the 3 fiends. Behind the door is another 
level up and from that moment on you can also build bridges. Now you 
can claim the area up to the Hatchery, and further on the entire 
place is trapped. See all those gravestones? They're actually Word-
of-Power traps in disguise. Better walk around them. Ignore all the 
Archers and Wizards around here for now and watch out for the 3 
boulders coming right at you! Any further than this becomes be bit 
vague to me.

It seems to be that there's only enough level ups to transform your 
level 1 Demon Spawn into a level 8 Dragon. Oddly, there are two 
"Transfer Creature" specials around, but I don't know whether the 
game allows you to transfer two creatures simultaneously (it could be 
the second one overwrites the first one).

---

**Secret 6 (Full moon bonus)**

```
Game Time:  20000 (~14 minutes)
Goal:       Mine 30001 gold within the time limit
Spells:     "Posses", "Create Imp", "Lightning"
Start Gold: 3000
Reward:     - (Bug I think, and no Ug the Barbarian... hmm Ug the B.)
Difficulty: *
Initial Creatures:
```

-

This level is only accessible on dates when the date of your 
Windows(R) Operating System clock is set to that of a full moon. If 
you wish to play this defunct level see this website for any full 
moons up to 2010:

http://www.moonphases.info/full_moon_calendar_dates.html

(set the date to 22-January 2008 also works :P). Set your Windows 
clock to any of those dates manually, and you'll see a flag with a 
white circle appear little to the SE of where Eversmile once was. 
Also a few days before/after the full moon the flag will appear 
transparently warning you about the upcoming/past event. Upon 
entering it you get to see the following objective text:

```
  "This region of the underworld will test your ability to traverse
   the network of caverns. Indeed, time is your enemy here. Defeat
   it and you will find where the legendary warrior, Ug the Barbarian
   is imprisoned. Ug will serve you well in the future."
```

However, there is are no creatures on the map and according to the 
script no creatures (apart from Tunnellers and Dwarfs) will be added 
during game play. Furthermore there is no "Transfer creature" spell 
to be found either so that rules out the possibility of transporting 
any creature to the next realm. Also, Ug that is an odd name that 
I've never seen appear on any Barbarian's name plate in this game. 
Why of all creatures a Hero and also a Barbarian? Lately, I've been 
suspecting a programmer's prank rather than a "bug" to be at the core 
of this issue. Suppose we write his name as: "Ug the B.". Now, it 
almost seems a little too obvious to tweak this to "the Bug". Hmmm.. 
This all seems too coincidental. Lastly, this level can be played at 
any moment in the game, but only on a full moon. A full moon has 
often been the subject of strange events in folklore and is also 
associated with insanity sometimes, mind you. ;)

For the level itself. It's pretty straightforward. During this 
mission all 4 Keepers (including you) have formed an alliance. The 
only opposition are some dwarfs which appear after subsequent amounts 
of gold have been dug up by all four Keepers cumulatively starting at 
20000. To make sure you survive the level, get some Imps out and dig 
to the southwest corner. Fortify the area around the portal here, 
because all adversaries originate from this and only this location. 
Now start digging gold like the other keepers. If you get more than 
30000 gold before time passes out you win the level. Press " " to 
continue... There's nothing else to do around here.

Comment: great answer, thanks. Is the bug correction script anywhere?